# PyErr_SetString does not raise the exception immediately(Swig)?

Tags: python, c, swig

I am wrapping a C lib to python module using SWIG. But exception does not seem to be raised at the right place, I have a simple demo for this,

**except_test.i**

```
%module except_test


%{
#include "except_test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%{
static int flagged_exception = 0;

void throw_except()
{
    flagged_exception = 1;
    printf("flag set \n");
}
%}

%exception {
    $action
    printf("exception block\n");
    if (flagged_exception) {
        printf("before setstring\n");
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, "test except");
        printf("after setstring\n");
        flagged_exception = 0;
    }
}
%include "except_test.h"
```

**except_test.c**

```
#include "except_test.h"


int except_test(int a) {

    if (a < 0) {
        throw_except();
        return 0;
    } else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

**run_except.py**

```
from except_test import *
import time

def test():
    b = except_test(-1)
    print 'b=', b

try:
    test()
except:
    print "caught exception"

for i in range(10):
    print i
    time.sleep(1)
```

Now if I run run_except.py

```
$python run_except.py 
flag set 
exception block
before setstring
after setstring
b= 0
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_except.py", line 15, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
RuntimeError: test except
```

as the output shows, the try/catch block didn't catch the exception.
Why is this? and How to avoid this?

Thanks,

Comment: Look at the generated code in _wrap.c file. Is the code in %exception there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return `NULL` from a Python extension to have it notice the error immediately:

```
if (flagged_exception) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, "test except");
    flagged_exception = 0;
    return NULL;
}
```

But using the generic SWIG macros will make the SWIG interface more portable to other languages.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `SWIG_fail;` right after `PyErr_SetString`. Alternatively, there is a convenient (and what's more important language-independent) macro `SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "error message")` wrapping `PyErr_SetString` and `SWIG_fail`.